# Do Makefiles support some sort of conditional dependencies based on whether a file exists?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

For example, I want to do something like this:

```
%.o: %.fast.c                       # Prefer this if %.fast.c exists
        $(CC) $(FASTFLAGS) $< -o $@

%.o: %.slow.c                       # Only if %.fast.c does not exist
        $(CC) $(SLOWFLAGS) $< -o $@
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Should it check to see if `%.slow.c` exists as well, or just assume it does?

Comment: @FiLeVeR10: Assume it does. But that doesn't matter because if you can check for one, you can check for the other.

Comment: If make can't build (or find) a prerequisite for a pattern rule then it won't use that rule (and another rule will be used instead). Think about the rules that build `.o` files from `.c`, `.cpp`, `.f`, etc. files.

Comment: @EtanReisner: But if *both* files exist, how can I ensure that it will always choose `%.fast.c` instead of `%.slow.c`?

Comment: The first matching rule should take precedence (when the stems are of equal length) I believe. (And the length thing is make 3.82+ only.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If make cannot find (and cannot build) a prerequisite of a pattern rule then make will not use that rule and another rule will be used instead. Consider the built-in rules that build `.o` files from a variety of sources (`.c`, `.cpp` and `.f` to name a few).

See the [How Patterns Match](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Pattern-Match) section of the makefile for more details about this.

The only caveat to be aware of with that manual section is that make prior to 3.81 did not have the shortest stem rule. That was a new addition in 3.82.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28544463/258523 has a good bit of information about this too, which is not at all surprising given the source.